# SSO under Atlassian products using Forgerock OpenAM

Tags: single-sign-on, jira, confluence, openam, opendj

I am looking for a current guide to configure single-sign-on (SSO) under Atlassian products like Jira and Confluence with the help of Forgerock OpenAM.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can integrate by replacing with the authenticator class. See also:

https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Integrate+with+Atlassian+Jira+and+Confluence

https://confluence.atlassian.com/crowd/integrating-crowd-with-atlassian-confluence-198573.html

http://azlabs.blogspot.jp/2014/09/integrate-openam-with-atlassian-jira.html

You can also integrate by SAML 2.0 (OpenAM acts as a SAML IdP):

https://resolution.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SSSO/SAML+Single+Sign+On